# Trigger Android talkback programmatically

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I've always looked to provide good accessibility support in my apps, but in my latest work, I've needed to build parts of the UI within a native OpenGL view, which means that there is no Android widgets or components on which one can hang a contentDescription or similar.

In theory, it shouldn't be too hard to implement "talkback" functionality regardless; just check whether talkback is switched on when the user taps a button and if it's the first tap, play the talkback text, and if a second consecutive, do what the button would normally do. But - somewhat to my surprise - there does not seem to be any APIs for this, or at least no documentation for them that I could find.

Anyone who has tried to work with the Android talkback functionality directly (or tried alternate solutions)? I'd hate to abandon those users who benefit from Talkback if there is a way to work around its seemingly limited implementation.

Comment: Did you see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views

Comment: Short answer: no. I've dug through a lot of that part of the site, but not gotten down to this part. Thanks for the lead.